# When is $\langle f_1^h, \ldots, f_r^h\rangle = \langle f^h : f \in I\rangle$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

Let $R = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and $S = R[t]$ be polynomial rings. 
Given a polynomial $f \in R$, $f^h \in S$ denotes the homogenization of $f$ w.r.t. the homogenization variable $t$.
For an ideal $I = \langle f_1, \ldots, f_r \rangle \subseteq R$, let

- $I^h = \langle f^h : f \in I\rangle$ denote the homogenization of $I$
- $\tilde{I} = \langle f_1^h, \ldots, f_r^h\rangle$ denote the ideal generated by the homogenized $f_i$'s

I want to show the following:

> If $t \nmid 0$ modulo $\tilde{I}$, then $\tilde{I} = I^h$.

Clearly, $\tilde{I} \subseteq I^h$ and I've read that equality only holds if $\{ f_1,\ldots,f_r\}$ is a Macaulay-basis of $I$ w.r.t. the standard grading of $R$.
However, I don't see how the assumption $t \nmid 0$ mod $\tilde{I}$ implies the other direction?